# What is the best collation which allows to consider equal German umlaut characters like 'UE'='Ü', 'AE'='Ä, 'ß'='ss'?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation, sql-server-collation

As title, I am looking for the best collation which allows to consider equal German characters like 'UE'='Ü', 'AE'='Ä, 'ß'='ss', etc.

Comment: Potential cross-site duplicate: [What's the meaning of the Collation Code (blank, 90, 100, 110) in SQL Server 2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/whats-the-meaning-of-the-collation-code-blank-90-100-110-in-sql-server-201)

Comment: You're also asking 2 different questions here: *1. What does the 100 mean? 2. What Collation can I use?* Questions should contain one *distinct* question (though a closely rated lead-on question can be appropriate). As you are asking 2 different questions here, which could easily result in close votes for the question being "too broad". I suggest focusing on one problem here; if you have a different question, ask another [New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: The query `select * from sys.fn_helpcollations() where name like 'German%'` returns over 60 German collations. Perhaps one of the Phonebook, Accent-Insensitive collations? Eg `German_PhoneBook_100_CI_AI` ?

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos yeah that's what I was thinking about, but I am wondering why the collation has PhoneBook inside its name. It works and there does not seem to be any other better choices so I will use that for now thank you.